# Pythonic way to find the nearest lower integer for x that is evenly divisible by N?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a more pythonic way than:

```
(x // n) * n
```

to find the nearest lower integer from `x` that `n` divides evenly?

Comment: what exactly is "unpythonic" about your approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the remainder!

```
answer = x - x%n
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `%` operator.

```
remainder = x%n
nearest_lower_integer_from_x = x - remainder
```

Comment: Longer, but effectively the same as inspectorG4dget's answer.

Comment: Only *archetypally*. A more appropriate term actually would be *more pedagogical*.